FileNotFoundError when trying to load a CSV file into pandas in Jupyter Notebook
I have been attempting to read data from a CSV file using a Python script in Jupyter Notebook. I expected the script to successfully load the CSV data into a pandas DataFrame without errors, however, I encountered a 'FileNotFoundError' indicating that the script could not locate the CSV file at the specified path. As a result, the script failed providing this error FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'customerss.csv'.
The CSV file works fine in Excel and I can read the data well but in Jupyter Notebook, it’s not working.
How do i solve such issue?

Have you tried providing the full path to the csv file, e.g., (assuming you're on Windows) "C:\Users\Username\Documents\customerss.csv"?

Another common approach to deal with this type of issue is to place the CSV in the same directory as the running Jupyter notebook. Windows can also make it tricky to designate paths correctly in Python. See here for more help in that. Also just watch out for typos. Use ls and pwd and %cd to explore from inside a notebook and use that it prints copied into your code. For example, customers and customerss are quite different for your system.

@Matt You need an r-prefix on that string otherwise you'll get an error about "truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape". Fixed: r"C:\Users\Username\Documents\customerss.csv"

@Wayne Are you sure that's the right link? It's talking about the colour of the interface, no mention of Windows or files or paths that I saw.

Yes, the link I meant is this one. Thanks for catching that.
